# How to disable a button even when it is not running in the background in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

When I say not running in the background, I mean when the user double clicked their home button and swipes up, the button will reenable

This is the code in my `viewDidLoad`

```
if let waitingDate:Date = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "waitingDate") as? Date
    {
        let currentDate = Date()

        if(currentDate.compare(waitingDate) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending)
        {
            getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

This is the code in the `@IBAction func`

```
getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = false

let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())

UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newDate, forKey: "waitingDate")
```

Comment: Try dateValue as! Date

Comment: And for enabling the button check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571194/using-nsuserdefaults-to-add-a-24hour-countdown-timer-in-swift

Comment: Try this : for set UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey:"yourKey") ....for get UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "yourKey") as! Date

Comment: If disabling your button is not working, check my updated answer.

Comment: Can you send me a link to it? My button does disable; however, if it is not running in the background it will reenable

Comment: Just everytime you are showing the button check if it should be enabled or not. And to the UserDefaults should be saved tomorrow's date when you press the button.

Comment: I updated my question to what I have in my code at the moment (is it correct for saving to the user defaults), can you write the code for "checking if it should me enabled or not"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value always check use guard or if let statement to prevent the crash:-

```
//Set value in user default 
UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey:"date")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

//Get value from user default 
guard let value = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "date") as? Date else {return}
print(value)
```

Comment: wait why can't the second one be `as! Date`

Comment: If your Date value is nil then it will crash.

Answer (score 3):

Save:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey:"date")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Retrieve:

```
if let dateValue = clickdate.object(forKey: "date") as? Date{
    ...
}
```

For enabling the button after 24 hours check this post:
[Enabling button after 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571194/using-nsuserdefaults-to-add-a-24hour-countdown-timer-in-swift)

If you want to disable the button for 24 hours then save tomorrow's date:

```
let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())
UserDefaults.standard.set(tomorrow, forKey:"date")
```

Checking if the button should be enabled:

```
let currentDate = Date()

if(currentDate.compare(dateValue) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending){
    //reenable button
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I checked out the other post and how would I change this `let newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.allZeros)` for the updated version of swift?

Comment: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())